# Why do I lose the context of this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code :

```
var o = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    f1: function ()
    {
        alert(this.b);
    }
}

var o2 = {
    a: 11,
    b: 22,
    f2: function (j)
    {
        j();
    }
}
```

But running this code :

`o2.f2(o.f1)` yields *undefined*. ( while im expecting "22" as a result)

Now, I know that the context has gone somewhere. and hence If I change the code in `o2` to :

```
 f2: function (j)
    {
        j.apply(this);
    }
```

It does work obviously.

But my question is :

- In what stage  did i lose the context ?

I don't understand : when `j()` is running , there **is** a `b` property  in the `o2` object.

What am I missing ?

**[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/olutig/2/edit)**

Comment: When you call it as `f()` - JavaScript methods are *"unbound functions"* (that is, unlike methods in other languages they are *not* associated with a particular object/instance) and it is the call-site that determines the `this` when invoked. (Of course, see [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or equivalent emulations.)

Comment: You lose it as soon as you pass around `o.f1`. If you do `var x = o.f1` and call `x()`, `f1` isn't bound anymore.

Comment: @Blender I know that. but why `this` is not regarding `o2` ? this is what i dont understand

Comment: @RoyiNamir `f()` is roughly equivalent to `window.f = f; window.f()` in how it affects `this` inside the invoked function. [Here are the gory details](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Why should it? It's unbound. Calling it doesn't magically bind it to the current context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found Crockford had an excellent description of the way this works. Functions in JavaScript can be invoked in 4 styles :

1. The "function" style
2. The "method" style
3. The "Constructor" style
4. The "call or apply" style.

I might be getting the exact names wrong there, but the spirit is the same.  You should definitely get the book "JavaScript: The Good Parts" if you don't have it.

So anyway - on to your question.  The key thing is that the value if "this" is dependant on which style you use.

```
// function invocation style, 
var f = function() { console.debug(this); }
f(); // "this" is bound to the global object.

// "method" invocation style
var obj = {
    f: function() { console.debug(this); }
};

obj.f(); // "this" is bound to "obj", the object on which the function was invoked

// so important bit is :

var f = obj.f;
f(); // "this" is global object
obj.f() // "this" is obj
```

In your example you are losing "this" because of the way you are *invoking* the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like as follows,

function will be called in o2 context

```
var o2 = {
    a: 11,
    b: 22,
    f2: function (j){
      this.temp = j;
      this.temp();
    }
};
```

also these will work too:

```
f2: function (j){
      j.apply(this);
}

f2: function (j){
      j.apply(o2);
}
```

Otherwise you call it just like an ordinary function out of context.

j Is ripped out of its context and you did no tricky closures on it(which is not your intent) so for making "this" work in it you need a scope. The this scope in your question for j is window, which has no "b" in it therefore you get an "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Check this tests:

```
o.f1(); // alerts 2

var f3 = o.f1; // (*)

f3(); // alerts undefined

o2.f2(f3); // alerts undefined

f3.apply(o2); // alerts 22
```

I realize that when you pass a function as parameter the context is lost exactly the same way it's lost in the `(*)` pointed in the code above.

What happening is `j = arguments[0] = o.f1` and at this point you lose the context.

When passes a function as a parameter you are just passing the reference in memory to that function. Without bind the context you'll fail the simple `j()` call. That's why you need to use `apply` or the `this` trick showed by Ihsan.