# Arrow Function with this Behaviour

Tags: javascript, this

Please tell me the behaviour of this in both situations. Why one shows 'window' and the other 'object'. Though they are called in the same manner by callback.

**CASE: 1**

```
let army = {
    minAge: 18,
    maxAge: 27,
    canJoin(user) {
        console.log(this);
    }
  };

function karan(callback){
    
    callback(); 
}  

karan(army.canJoin);
```

**Result is WINDOW OBJECT**

**CASE: 2**

```
let army = {
    minAge: 18,
    maxAge: 27,
    canJoin(user) {
        console.log(this);
    }
  };


function karan(callback){
    
    callback(); 
}  


karan( () => army.canJoin());
```

**RESULT: THE OBJECT**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I lose the context of this in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382165/why-do-i-lose-the-context-of-this-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a context object, it will be passed to the function at the time of *execution*. One of the ways to specify the context is through calling it as a method on an object.

**CASE: 1**

You are sending *only* the function `army.canJoin` to `karan` as `callback`

```
karan(army.canJoin);
```

At this point the function is detached from the original context object, then you are executing it when you call `callback()`

```
function karan(callback){
    callback(); // when the function is called here, there is no explicit context,
    // `this` will default to the window object in browser environment.
}
```

**CASE: 2**

The function is executed when the original context is attached to it

```
army.canJoin() // the context or `this` is still army object
```

Note that for this specific case. It's not related to the arrow function,
if you do the following, you will still get `this` as the army object

```
karan(function(){ army.canJoin() })
```

Answer (score -1):

In case 1, you're experiencing what's sometimes called "context loss". Once the function `army.canJoin` has been passed into `karan`, it loses the "context" of `army`, so `this` defaults to being the `window` object.

In case 2, where you do `army.canJoin()`, you are calling `canJoin` "as a method of army", rather than as a standalone function. This means `this` will be the object which you're using to access `canJoin` via the dot operator.

for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16382577/9011089